# Problem with "\newlist" of the "enumitem" package

Tags: errors, lists, enumitem

I don't know why this code generates an *error*.

> ! Package enumitem Error: Undefined
>   label.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{mylist}{enumerate}{1}
\begin{document}
\begin{mylist}
\item a
\end{mylist}
\end{document}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You must add at least a `\setlist[mylist,1]{label=\arabic*}` command (or whatever formatting you want for the label).

Comment: The `enumitem` package should have an *default setting* as that.

Comment: It does - it is the `enumerate` environment ;). The idea of `\newlist` is that you explicitly want to define a new one from scratch. At least, that's how I have always read it.

Comment: @cfr An answer? Your comment is a good starting point.

Comment: @egreg I don't like post answers to my own questions based on comment of others users, i find it distasteful and dishonest. If someone want to post an answer i will accept it.

Comment: @skpblack I asked cfr to provide one. But there's nothing bad in self answering if you think that a comment put you on the right track.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As Bernard mentioned, if the list is a new one, you need to set at least the label because, in this case, you are creating a new list from scratch. If you just want to alter attributes of the default lists, you can instead specify `enumerate`, for example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{leftmargin=0pt}%  if you just want to change some aspect of the default enumerate environment
\newlist{mylist}{enumerate}{1}%         if you want to create a new list from scratch
\setlist[mylist,1]{label=\roman*)}%     in that case, at least label must be specified using \setlist
\begin{document}
  This is some text. This is some more text. This is yet further text. This is also text. So, it seems, is this. The text continues on.
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item first level has zero left margin
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item second level is untouched
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
  This is an interlude consisting of some more text.
  \begin{mylist}
    \item a
  \end{mylist}
\end{document}
```

[image: enumerations]

Comment: In the `\setlist[mylist,1]{label=\roman*)}` case, can I inherit the label from `enumerate`? Or, do I always need to explicitly set the label format?